Proving that a certain function is convex
Let $k=\arccos(\frac{1}{4})$, and let $f(x)=\arccos(\cos(x)\cdot\cos(kx))$. Prove that $f$ is concave ($f''(x)<0$) in the interval $\left(0,1\right)$.
Note that the function $f(x)$ is the length of the `hypotenuse' of a right spherical triangle with legs $x,kx$ (see the spherical cosine rule)
Context: I am trying to prove some lemmas about spherical trigonometry and I need this function to be convex in order to apply Jensen's inequality.

It is not concave/convex for all values of k.

Denote $c = \cos x, s = \sin x, c_1 = \cos kx, s_1 = \sin kx$. Then $c, s, c_1, s_1 > 0$ on $(0, 1)$.
We have
$$f''(x) = -\frac{1}{(1 - c^2 c_1^2)^{3/2}}(2kss_1 - cc_1k^2s^2 - cc_1 s_1^2).$$
It suffices to prove that, for all $x \in (0, 1)$
$$2kss_1 - cc_1k^2s^2 - cc_1 s_1^2 > 0.$$
@Saúl RM's approach:
We have
$$kss_1 - cc_1 s_1^2 \ge kss_1 - s_1^2
= s_1 (ks - s_1) > 0$$
where we use $ks - s_1 = k\sin x - \sin kx > 0$.
We have
$$kss_1 - cc_1 k^2 s^2
= ksc_1 (s_1/c_1 - cks) > 0$$
where we use $s_1/c_1 - cks
= \tan kx - k \cos x \sin x
\ge k x - k \cos x \sin x
= \frac12 k (2x - \sin 2x) > 0$
(using $\tan kx \ge kx$).
We are done.

Thanks. Did you use some software to obtain the expression for the second derivative? (Just so I can reproduce it)

@SaúlRM You can use Maple. Actually, you can do it by hand.

Thanks, I think I made some mistake computing by hand

By the way, it seems once you have the expression you give for the second derivative, to obtain the inequality $2kss_1 - cc_1k^2s^2 - cc_1 s_1^2 > 0$ it is enough to check that $kss_1\geq cc_1s_1^2$ (which is easy because $ks\geq s_1$) and that $kss_1\geq cc_1k^2s^2$, i.e, $s_1\geq cc_1ks$, which follows from the fact that $\tan(kx)\geq kx\geq c_1(x)ks(x)$

@SaúlRM Yes, your idea is much simpler.

@SaúlRM I edited my answer to use your approach.
